# how to get latitude and longitude from a marker and populate in a textbox using c#

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps

How can I populate the latitude and longitude of the marker in the textboxes when each marker is added?

I am trying to populate the textboxes in order to be able to save the latitude and longitude in database and be able to view the saved details by a user.
I am using a script where on click on the map, a marker will be added but I'm not being able to save the marker.

Here is my code:

```
`<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">

    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
window.onload = function () {
var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(21.0000, 78.0000),
    zoom: 5,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
};
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("dvMap"), mapOptions);

//Attach click event handler to the map.
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function (e) {

    //Determine the location where the user has clicked.
    var location = e.latLng;

    //Create a marker and placed it on the map.
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: location,
        map: map
    });

    //Attach click event handler to the marker.
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function (e) {
        var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: 'Latitude: ' + location.lat() + '<br />Longitude: ' + location.lng()
        });
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
    });
});
};
 </script>

</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div id="dvMap" style="width: 500px; height: 500px">
</div>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLongitude" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtLatitude" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: I have tried populating the textboxes in the code behind but its not good as i'n not being able to call the function location.lat() and location.lng()

Comment: You'll need to populate the text inputs on the client side by finding them in the DOM e.g. `document.getElementById('id of control')` and setting the `value` property. One thing to note will be controlling the client id that ASP.NET generates for the TextBox controls

Comment: I have try doing this but it does not work.

Can you please give me a more precise example..

    'function getValue(location) {
    var txt=document.getElementById("longitude").value;
    txt=txt + location;
    document.getElementById("longitude").value=txt;    
    }'

    '<input id="longitude" runat="server" type="text" />'